# Reflexive pronoun in a prepositional phrase modifying a noun

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

I recently saw the sentence

> She knew what he was talking about because of a previous conversation between **themselves**.

Why is the reflexive pronoun *themselves* used instead of *them*? Would

> She knew what he was talking about because of a previous conversation between **them**.

be incorrect?

Comment: between them would refer to other parties. themselves is the only way to refer to her and him.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree slightly with Lambdie's answer from 2018.

The writer might have used 'themselves' to remove ambiguity, and that's certainly a legitimate reason to say 'between themselves' rather than 'between them', but there would be nothing inherently wrong with saying 'because of a previous conversation between them', especially in a context when there are clearly no other people involved.

Personally, I find 'between themselves' sounds cludgy unless it is absolutely necessary. I think most people would say either 'because of a previous conversation between them' or 'because of their previous conversation'.

Comprehension of language depends enormously on context, and if the context makes a meaning obvious, it's better to go with the most succinct option.

Comment: She knew what he was talking about because of a previous conversation between themselves. She and he. Versus: She knew what he was talking about because of a previous conversation between them. them=other people, not she and him. For example: the boys on the team.

Answer (score 0):

- To have a conversation **with one another or each other.** versus: to have a conversation with others.
- To converse **with one another or each other.**

We had three conversations [**with each other**] during the week.

The phrase "**with each other or one another**"is a signal for a reflexive pronoun:

- We had three conversations [**between ourselves**] during the week. That means "We spoke to each other three times in conversations." They had a conversation [between themselves]". In other words, between themselves and not between themselves and other people.

Please note: "We had 10 apples between us." When you read that, you do not know which individual had what number of apples. The same would be true of conversations.

Question: "How many [phone] conversations did the three friends have that week?"
Answer: I don't know how many each had, but they had **5 conversations between them.**

- between them refers to some number of conversations (or items) per person
- between themselves refers to conversations engaged in by two (or more) people with each other.

That said, colloquially, people do say: conversation between them, but you can see where it might be misleading with my example, and why themselves is more accurate.

- She knew what he was talking about because of a previous conversation between them. [not her and him, but him and others].
- She knew what he was talking about because of a previous conversation between themselves. [between her and him]